# TYPO3 v9 slug fallback for chinese, russian or arabic URLs to latin language

Tags: url, utf-8, typo3, slug

To avoid special characters in the URL is it possible in TYPO3 v9 to define a fallback to another language e.g. english?

Before:

mydomain.org/cn/企业/

After:

mydomain.org/cn/company/

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is to use the hook within SlugHelper.

You can add a postModifier like this in your own extension:

```
$GLOBALS[TCA][pages][columns][slug][config][generatorOptions][postModifiers][Vendor\Package] = My\Class::class . '->modifySlug';
```

You will have the following hook parameters available.

```
$hookParameters = [
    'slug' => $slug,
    'workspaceId' => $this->workspaceId,
    'configuration' => $this->configuration,
    'record' => $recordData,
    'pid' => $pid,
    'prefix' => $prefix,
    'tableName' => $this->tableName,
    'fieldName' => $this->fieldName,
];
```

Your own hook method returns a modified slug. The record should contain the information about the language.

This way you could actually write your own code or fetch the default language slug and add it there.